# invalid url giving regexmatcherror and not raising error when invalid url is given in pytube program

Tags: python, error-handling, pytube

```
try:
    link = input("Enter URL of video you would like to download") 
except RegexMatchError:
    print("error")
```

I am using Pytube to download youtube videos I have everything done however, I want to raise an error whenever an invalid URL or input is given. Whenever I type in an invalid inputI  see RegexMatchError in the console but I don't see my error message just the one given to me by Pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the error type like:

```
try:
    link = input("Enter URL of video you would like to download") 
except Exception:
    print("error")
```